# What is MarkSelection in Eclipse, it will be used in what scenario?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I know `StructuredSelection` will be used when you select a file in Package Explorer for example, and `TextSelection` will be used when you select some text in Editor, but not clear about `MarkSelection`, when it will be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MarkSelection` is generated by `TextViewer` (so usually a text editor) and reports a change to a 'mark' selection. It will only be sent to selection change listeners for the text viewer.

The `TextViewer.setMark` method causes the mark selection changed event to be generated. This only seems to be used by incremental search and for marked regions used in Emacs style editing.